# Error while trying to run composer install

Tags: laravel-5, dependencies, composer-php, orchestra

I am running into an issue while trying to install dependencies w/ composer. I have tried updating the orchestra version\ laravel version to try and meet each others needs. Can't seem to find a solution. Anyone else run into this problem?

After running `composer install` I get the error

```
Problem 1
    - orchestra/testbench v3.9.4 requires laravel/framework ^6.18.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - orchestra/testbench v3.9.3 requires laravel/framework ^6.18.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - orchestra/testbench v3.9.2 requires laravel/framework ^6.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v6.10.0, v6.10.1, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v6.9.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - orchestra/testbench v3.9.1 requires laravel/framework ^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.10.1, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v6.9.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - orchestra/testbench v3.9.0 requires laravel/framework ^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.10.1, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v6.9.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.36
    - orchestra/testbench v3.8.5 requires laravel/framework ~5.8.35 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.38].
    - orchestra/testbench v3.8.6 requires laravel/framework ~5.8.35 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.38].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.20
    - orchestra/testbench v3.8.3 requires laravel/framework ~5.8.19 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.19, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.38].
    - orchestra/testbench v3.8.4 requires laravel/framework ~5.8.19 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.19, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.38].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
    - orchestra/testbench v3.8.2 requires laravel/framework ~5.8.3 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.38, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.3
    - orchestra/testbench v3.8.1 requires laravel/framework ~5.8.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.38, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.2
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-debugbar dev-master -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-debugbar[dev-master].
    - Installation request for orchestra/testbench ~3.8 -> satisfiable by orchestra/testbench[v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.8.2, v3.8.3, v3.8.4, v3.8.5, v3.8.6, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2, v3.9.3, v3.9.4].
    - barryvdh/laravel-debugbar dev-master requires illuminate/support ^6|^7 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, 
v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, 
v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.12.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.13.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.13.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.14.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.15.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.15.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.16.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.17.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.17.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.12.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.13.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.14.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.14.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.15.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.16.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.16.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.17.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.17.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.17.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.18.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.19.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.19.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.20.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.21.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.22.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.22.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.22.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.22.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.22.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.23.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.23.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.23.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.24.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.25.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.8.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.9.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.9.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.9.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - orchestra/testbench v3.8.0 requires laravel/framework ~5.8.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.0, v5.8.1, v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.38, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].      
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.1
```

My composer dependencies look like this:

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "dev-master",
        "cartalyst/sentinel": "2.0.*",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^6.7",
        "laravel/framework": "~5.8",
        "laravel/nexmo-notification-channel": "^2.3",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.8.*",
        "laravelcollective/remote": "^5.8",
        "laravelium/sitemap": "^3.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "orchestra/testbench": "~3.8",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.8",
        "mockery/mockery": "1.2.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "8.1.*"
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in that long list of dependency resolving attempts, you require `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` from the latest master branch. This requires Laravel v6 or v7, while you require `laravel/framework` in v 5.8.

Usually, you should not install master branches if there is no really good reason to do so. In your environment, the solution is pretty simple: install `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` in v3.4 (for example by replacing `dev-master` with `^3.4`)